# microcontroller serial communication noisy on direct wire connection

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, noise, logic-gates, inverter

I did a simple circuit to test data communication between two separate microcontroller circuits.
The big X is actually two wires (not touching each other) that connects the two circuits together.

Each inverter IC has its own 3.3V source from a regulated 5VDC source via voltage regulators.

The reason I'm using 3.3V is because I'll replace the wires with radio modules that can't accept more than 3.9VDC.

The microcontroller code itself runs as expected (I verified it in software simulation and on the board countless times with LED lights)

I even further debugged code by replacing a microcontroller with a max232 so I can collect data on the PC.

When I examined the data, much of it was accurate but there were some bytes that were not expected. The values were off by one bit being incorrect in most cases.

At the moment, I'm waiting for 74HCT14's in the mail and I will see if that makes a difference since they don't react terrible to sudden short spikes like the 74HCT04's do (or am I wrong?)

I'm also open to other IC's that work as drop-in replacements for 74HCT04 and LM1117-3.3 that would make the data transmission more smooth.

For my PCB I made my tracks short and wide (2mm width) and spacing is at least 12mils.

The data speed for communication is 38400bps.

I'm also tempted to throw in resistors somewhere in the receiving path (between inverter and microcontroller pin)

What else can I do to ensure the line is noise-free?

[image: circuit]

Comment: How about making it a twisted pair? You can't _guarantee_ that a transmission line is 100% free of noise. That's impossible. You can reduce it as much as possible like a twisted pair or your signals being very close to ground but there will always be some type of external electromagnetic activity. We're surrounded by it constantly with radio waves from cell phone towers, the sun has ultraviolet radiation, etc. Side note that if you can't find a twisted pair, strip an ethernet cord. They have three or four depending on the connector.

Comment: Like-it-or-not, your comm-link has a *third* wire...GND. You just might be able to reduce noise by reducing its loop area. @KingDuken has suggested twisted pair (that's a good way to reduce area). Beware of adding "extra" ground loops. A better solution uses differential line receivers & transmitters with twisted pair. If your noise *is a ground problem* it may go away when you substitute RF modules.

Comment: Whatever the problem here this whole investigation is probably a dead end.  You can't expect clean communication over a radio link, so don't try to put a wireline protocol over one, which makes whatever your difficulty in this question happens to be mostly irrelevant to your actual goal.  Realistically, if you want to move data, buy packetized data radios like nRF24's or the various sub-GHz FSK offerings from TI, SiLabs, Hope, Semtech, etc.

Comment: While it's unlikely to be the issue, if one were serious about building this, 22 uF positioned by the regulator is more of a *supply filter* capacitor than a bypass capacitor.  Each of the processor and hex inverter ICs should get something like a 100 nF cap as close to being directly across their power pins as possible.   You can add that on top of the IC if you like, though surface mount right next to the power pin and going through a via to a big ground plane on the back would be still better.  But chips with the power pins physically so separated have lower needs than modern ones.

Answer (score 1):

There are some serious issues in your circuit that cause it to act erratically.

First of all, HCT chips are not meant to be run at 3.3V. Just look at any HCT chip datasheet. They need a supply between 4.5V and 5.5V to run properly. Most likely you do not want to use HCT but maybe HC chips that can work at 3.3V, but it will also have problems.

Second problem is that the MCU uses open drain outputs with internal weak pull-ups to 5V. It basically means that the 5V TX signal from MCU will actually try to power the HCT chip via the input protection diodes. Fortunately the internal pull-ups are very weak so it may not cause the 3.3V to rise much, but do measure the 3.3V voltage and see if it is unexpectedly high. This will be an issue with HC type chips as well.

Third problem may be that the MCU outputs are open-drain. The rising edge only depends on the MCU internal pull-up resistance so the edge can be so slow that communication fails due to data pin spending more time low than high. So a pull-up resistor (in this case something like 4k7 ohms to 3.3V) might be needed at MCU TX pin. To see if this is an issue you really need an oscilloscope.

Then you need to have the device grounds at same potential, so you must have RX, TX and Ground between the devices, simply the TX and RX are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. IC3/4 E/F inverters do more harm than good for your circuit, as they introduce new noise that is not in phase with noise on Tx/Rx lines. Connect the ends of 3rd wire directly to GND on each side instead.
2. Replacing inverters with MAX232 would spread logic voltages of the signal to RS232 levels thus making it more immune to noise. However this solution does not make a good emulation for radio channel. For proper emulation of duplex radio connection, one should use two differential lines (4 wires), e.g. with optocouplers.
3. For keeping it simple, the circuit might work as is with small changes:

   - fix the ground as above,
   - better yet, use two twisted pairs of CAT5 cable, terminated at receive end (IC3B-9, IC4C-5).
   - Termination resistance to be calculated so that output current of driving inverter never exceeds max allowed. HCT will not allow (by far) reaching the impedance match for twisted pair (120 Ohm). Replacement with ACT or LVC series would be a lot better. Not necessary inverters, a tiny driver like 74LVC2G34 will work.

Comment: I suspect, or at least *hope* that what you are looking at is just the input termination of the unused gates in a hex inverter package, and that there's a common ground wire not shown.  This poster has, however, been pursuing a very odd approach to things so it is hard to know.

Comment: @Chris Stratton a valid point, but then why daisy-chaining E/F modules instead of grounding them all?